# Настройки приватности при публикации фото в Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-api

Как-нибудь настраиваются? Используется Graph API, библиотека [Facebook Platform Python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk). Если да, то любопытно было бы посмотреть на простенькие примеры. У самого получалось только публиковать и не понятно, как менять область видимости этого объекта (пример - фото), другими участниками сети, выборочно.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это невозможно, и об этом написано в доках.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?